How can I do one-hot encoding from multiple columns
When I search for this topic, I get answers that do not match what I want to do. Let's say I have a table like this:



Item
N1
N2
N3
N4




Item1
1
2
4
8


Item2
2
3
6
7


Item3
4
5
7
9


Item4
1
5
6
7


Item5
3
4
7
8



I would like to one-hot encode this to get:



Item
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9




Item1
1
1
0
1
0
0
0
1
0


Item2
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
0
0


Item3
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
0
1


Item4
1
0
0
0
1
1
1
0
0


Item5
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
0



Is this feasible at all?  I am now in the process of coding some sort of loop to go through each line but I decided to ask if anyone knows a more efficient way to do this.

Use melt and crosstab.
tmp = df.melt('Item')
result = pd.crosstab(tmp['Item'], tmp['value']).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

    Item  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  Item1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
1  Item2  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
2  Item3  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1
3  Item4  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
4  Item5  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0


With pd.crosstab, you can use the colnames parameter to avoid the need to chain df.rename_axis. I.e., pd.crosstab(tmp['Item'], tmp['value'], colnames=[None]).reset_index().

What if the column 'item' is a datetimeindex instead of a regular column?  Apparently datetimeindex does not have an attribute melt.

I can't reproduce the error... By any chance, is the column set as index? if so, just use tmp = df.unstack().reset_index(name='N') instead of melt and after that use crosstab

You can try pd.get_dummies, e.g.,
pd.get_dummies(df.melt('Item'), columns=['value'], prefix='', prefix_sep='').drop('variable', axis=1).groupby('Item').sum().reset_index()

which gives
    Item  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  Item1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
1  Item2  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
2  Item3  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1
3  Item4  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
4  Item5  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0

Data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Item": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"],
        "N1": [1, 2, 4, 1, 3],
        "N2": [2, 3, 5, 5, 4],
        "N3": [4, 6, 7, 6, 7],
        "N4": [8, 7, 9, 7, 8],
    }
)


Hi, I am the OP. I selected Triky's answer because It does what I want (i.e.) labels are the actual numbers. But your solution is very good as well and I can think of some case where it would be better to have a named label. Thanks for that.

@Eric no problem. You can check my update

Another possible solution, using sklearn. This solution utilizes sklearn's MultiLabelBinarizer to one-hot encode specific columns of df. Its steps are:

First, it initializes the MultiLabelBinarizer and applies its fit_transform method to the values of columns N1 through N4, converting them into a binary matrix where each unique value is represented as a separate column.

A new dataframe is then created from this binary matrix, with columns named after the unique values identified by binarize.classes_.

Finally, pd.concat is used to combine the original Item column with the newly created one-hot encoded dataframe.


from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

binarize = MultiLabelBinarizer()
pd.concat(
    [df[['Item']], 
     pd.DataFrame(
         binarize.fit_transform(df[['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4']].values), 
         columns=binarize.classes_)], axis=1)

NB: To avoid enumerating all columns starting with N, @ThomasIsCoding, to whom I thank, suggests, in a comment bellow, to use:
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith("N")]

or
df.iloc[:,1:]

Output:
    Item  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  Item1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
1  Item2  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
2  Item3  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1
3  Item4  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
4  Item5  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0


This is also very good for the simple fact that it is very easy to understand what is going on.

interesting approach with MultiLabelBinarizer, +1!

Thanks, @ThomasIsCoding! I am now working in machine learning, and that inspired this solution.

haha, sklearn is indeed a treasure island :D. One minor comment: probably you can use df.iloc[:,1:] to avoid enumerating all columns starting with N, or df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith("N")], in case there are a large number of columns like that

Thanks, @ThomasIsCoding, for your comment! I have meanwhile updated my answer accordingly.
